# Emacs buffer-local font

Tags: emacs, fonts

For all my tasks I use URW Chancery L font in Emacs. But for some tasks, 
like org-mode tables, shell or sunrise-commander, I would like to set mono-width font.
So, my question, how can I do it? All I found about it is `set-default-font`, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 11):

Faces (i.e. the objects used to specify appearence of text such as font, color, ...) are mostly global in Emacs, although they can also be set on a frame basis, so you can do the above by creating a separate frame and change the `default' face to use in that frame.
This said, Emacs can also now also change face's appearence for specific buffers via *face-remapping*.  E.g.

```
(face-remap-add-relative 'default '(:family "Monospace"))
```

should make the current buffer use Monospace.  So adding the above to `org-mode-hook` might just solve your problem.

Comment: Same effect -- affect only cyrillic. Is it any way to insert screeshots into SO?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet sets the "Arial" font family only in C mode:

```
(defun set-my-font ()
  (overlay-put (make-overlay (point-min) (point-max) nil nil t)
               'face '(:family "Monospace")))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'set-my-font)
```

Replace with `org-mode-hook` with the desired mode(s), and it should work as well.

This solution effects creation of buffer-local font by setting the font family property of an overlay over the entire buffer. The overlay's `face` property only specifies the font family (`Monospace`), and Emacs redisplay is smart enough to merge it with other text properties, such as the colors specified by `font-lock`.

Comment: I replaced in your example family with `Monospace`, and strangely, it helps only with cyrillic symbols. Tables in org mode are still visually not vertical.

Comment: Can you instruct me how to get an org mode table? I'm not an org-mode user, and the trivial things I tried seemed to work fine.

Comment: In `org-mode` printf header, with `|` separated, like `foo|bar|baz|'. Then press Enter, insert '|' and press Tab. You will get aligned cells. Well, visually alligned only for monowidth.

Comment: It still seems to work for me. Steps to repeat: 1. emacs -q; 2. `M-x customize-face RET default RET`, set family to `Arial` or other proportional font; 3. Run the code from the (revised) answer; 4. Switch to a new buffer and run `M-x org-mode RET`; 5. input `foo|bar|baz RET RET RET`. After these steps, I see contents of the buffer in a monospace font, with cells correctly aligned. Emacs version is 24.2.1, org-mode version is 7.8.11.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to customize `org-table` ?

You can modify it with `org-menu > Customize > Customize > org-table`

or use the command line

`M-x set-face-font RET org-table RET -PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1`

Use tab to auto-complete and see other available fonts

Finaly you could also directly modify you init.el to have something like

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-table ((t (:foreground "LightSkyBlue" :family "DejaVu Sans Mono")))))
```